# Jquery display checkbox`s value in div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, checkbox

I have this script which lets me to display value (text) which is next to the checkbox (aspx). On checkbox change text is shown in the div separated by commas. Somehow if any of the checkbox is checked and then di-checked, the value does not disappear from JobIDs var. What im missing here?

```
 $(document).data('JobNumbers', "");
 $('[id*=projectchk] input').change(function() {
    var JobIDs = "";
    var JobIDs = $(':checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).closest("span").find("label").html();
    }).get().join(', ');
    var JobNumbers = "<label> Reference Job #:</label> " + JobIDs;
    $('#job_numbers').html(JobNumbers);
    if (JobIDs != "") {
        $(document).data('JobNumbers', JobNumbers);
    }
    return false;
 });
```

So if 3 checkboxes are selected it shows:

[image]

But even if I di-select all of them it still shows the last one:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you di-select all of them, that statement becomes `false`:

```
if (JobIDs != "") {
    $(document).data('JobNumbers', JobNumbers);
}
```

And so your code is not executed.

EDIT: If you don't want to display the label in the case no option is selected, I think this sould work:

```
 $(document).data('JobNumbers', "");
 $('[id*=projectchk] input').change(function() {
    var JobIDs = "";
    JobIDs = $(':checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).closest("span").find("label").html();
    }).get().join(', ');
    var JobNumbers = "";
    if (JobIDs != "") {
        JobNumbers = "<label> Reference Job #:</label> " + JobIDs;
    }
    $('#job_numbers').html(JobNumbers);
    $(document).data('JobNumbers', JobNumbers);
    return false;
 });
```

Here's also a good practice tip: you don't need to write `var` every time you use a variable, only when you declare it. I also strongly recommend you to have some reading about JavaScript `let` and `const` =)

Comment: Ok, so my question from here would be, if all checkboxes are di-selected, how can I make #job_numbers div empty again ? It is empty in the begining before the function is executed.

Comment: if you execute that code without the if statement, wouldn't it work?

Comment: Yes, the issues with the value leftover is solved. But the <label> is still remain.

Comment: Just edited my answer. Please check it out and feedback me @Fresher

Comment: works. thanks Arthur. Sometimes its easier than you think!